# How to construct a function that will construct a histogram or a bar chart depending the variable

Tags: r, function, bar-chart, histogram

How can I construct a function (in base R)which will receive as an input parameter a variable, and will construct a histogram or a bar chart depending on whether it will be a quantitative or categorical variable?

I have tried googling but the solution has to be found witout an extra package downloaded

Answer (score 2):

### Function

Assuming you are working with `numeric` variables or `factor`. But you can keep putting `if else`s there for all kinds of variables.

```r
plot_hist_or_bar <- function(x) {
  if(is.numeric(x)) {
    hist(x)
  } else if(is.factor(x)) {
    barplot(table(x))
  } else {
    stop("Input variable must be numeric or a factor.")
  }
}
```

### Testing

```r
x <- rnorm(100)
plot_hist_or_bar(x)
```

[image]

```r
y <- factor(rep(c("A", "B"), 50))
plot_hist_or_bar(y)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>